# Is there a problem in 'react-metismenu-router-link' with react16?

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

in the use of library 'react-metismenu' there is not problem and work correctly,but this use anchor for selecting item of menu. that is not good.
so to use react-router-link i use 'react-metismenu-router-link' library
but this error accured:(

> Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
>   this.context.router.history.listen(this.onLocationChange.bind(this));

how to fix this problem?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-metismenu-router-link

Answer (score 1):

There's an open [PR](https://github.com/alpertuna/react-metismenu-router-link/pull/13) to fix this bug but the original repository has been archived so it won't be merged.

You can checkout [jhillhouse92's fork of react-metismenu-router-link](https://github.com/jhillhouse92/react-metismenu-router-link) and install this package instead of the original one, it includes the code of the PR.

Edit: I'm adding more information as suggested.
This bug is caused by the use of Context API instead of props in RouterLink component, as you can see in the PR.

These are the bug causing lines in RouterLink.jsx :

```
this.context.router.history.listen(this.onLocationChange.bind(this));
this.onLocationChange(this.context.router.route);
```

jhillhouse92 commits are replacing context with props:

```
  class RouterLink extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      this.to = this.props.to;
      if (this.to[0] !== '/') this.to = `/${this.to}`;

      // He is using props.history instead of context.router.history
      // and props.location instead of context.router.route
      this.props.history.listen(this.onLocationChange.bind(this));
      this.onLocationChange(this.props.location);
    }

    onLocationChange(e) {
      if ((e.pathname || '/') === this.to) {
        this.props.activateMe();
      }
    }
```

We are also adding withRouter in the export of our RouterLink component to give him react-router-dom related props (e.g. props.history):

```
export default withRouter(RouterLink);
```

Applying these changes, either by installing the package from git or editing manually should solve your bug.

Comment: Hi Dario de cianni, welcome. Please consider adding more information because if the links becomes obsolete, then you have a very low quality answer.

Comment: I've added some explanation of what jhillhouse92 was trying to merge to the repo, hoping the answer is now clearer and won't become osbolete.